# show loading bar when parent component pass data to and render child component. React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component, react-state

I am loading a child component on parent component in React.js. With a click on the button, data will be pass to child component through props, and child component will map through that data and render on screen. I am getting data from localstorage and processing its data structure to child component.
But, the issue is when I click on the button and data is being passed and rendered, the button is shown and after the child component is rendered that shows up. I need the loading spinner when I click on the button and it disappears and shows the actual component.
I have tried methods like `loading: false` in the state but to no avail.

Thanks for your help

```
import ShowPatientAppointments from './ShowPatientAppointments.component';

class PatientAppointmnent extends Component {
    state = {
        doctorSlots: null,
        timingSlot: null,
        bookDay: null,
        bookTime: null,
        hasTiming: false,
    }

    getSlots = () => {
        let slot = [];
        let time = [];
        
        for (let i=0; i< localStorage.length; i++) {
            let key = localStorage.key(i);
            let value = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
            slot.push(key);
            time.push(value);
            
            this.setState({doctorSlots: slot, timingSlot: time});
        }
        console.log(this.state.doctorSlots, this.state.timingSlot);
    }


    render() {
        const { doctorSlots, timingSlot, hasTiming } = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
               
                <button onClick={this.getSlots} className='button'>Show me dates</button>

                {doctorSlots === null ? <p></p> : <PatientSelectDay props={doctorSlots} timing={timingSlot} getTimings={this.getTiming} />}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PatientAppointmnent;


class PatientSelectDay extends Component {
state = {  
      options: [...this.props.props].map(obj => {
        return {value: `${obj}`, label: `${obj}`}
      }),
      timingOptions: [...this.props.timing],
      open_id: [],
      part_id: '',
      doctorDay: 'day',
      doctorTiming: 'timing',
  }

  changeSingleHandler = e => {
    this.setState({ part_id: e ? e.value : '' });
  };

  changeHandler = e => {
    let add = this.state.open_id;
    add.push(e.map(x => x.value));
    this.setState({ open_id: e ? add : [] });
  };

  saveState = (option) => {
...save selected options
  }  

  render() {
    const {options, timingOptions} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
            <div className='carousel'>
          {options.map((option, index) => {
                const timing = timingOptions[index].map(obj => {
                  return {value: `${obj}`, label: `${obj}`}});
                return(
                <div key={index}>
                  <Select
                    name="open_id"
                    value={option}
                    onChange={this.changeSingleHandler}
                    options={option}
                    className='select'
                  /> 
                  <Select
                    name="open_id"
                    value={this.state.open_id}
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    options={timing}
                    className='select'
                  /> 
            <button onClick={() => this.saveState(option)} className='button-left'>Select Days</button>
            </div>
            )
  })}
            </div>
          </div>
          )
    }
  }
export default PatientSelectDay;
```

Comment: Pass a function that sets loading to false to the child, and call it in the child's `componentDidMount()`

Comment: As per your logic and design... loader should be shown till we don't have doctorSlots avaiable. Though hasTiming state is never used by you, and never changed to true... But if we go by your logic only, make a small change within render() of parent component make this addition and see if LOADING appears on the screen. 
 {doctorSlots === null ? <p> LOADING ...</p> : <PatientSelectDay /> . You Loader Spinner should replace <p>LOADING ...</p>... Do this small modification and let me know

Comment: I have already did {doctorSlots === null ? <p> LOADING ...</p>. it shows loading all the time until I press the button. But I need loading only when I press the button and show a loading until <PatientSelectDay /> loads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code adding a `loading` state variable.

```
class PatientAppointmnent extends Component {
    state = {
        doctorSlots: null,
        timingSlot: null,
        bookDay: null,
        bookTime: null,
        hasTiming: false,
        loading: false
    }

    getSlots = () => {
        let slot = [];
        let time = [];
        
        this.setState({
          loading: true
        })
        
        for (let i=0; i< localStorage.length; i++) {
            let key = localStorage.key(i);
            let value = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
            slot.push(key);
            time.push(value);
            
            this.setState({doctorSlots: slot, timingSlot: time, loading: false});
        }
        console.log(this.state.doctorSlots, this.state.timingSlot);
    }
    
    renderButton = () => {
            const { doctorSlots, timingSlot, loading } = this.state;
        if(doctorSlots === null && timingSlot === null) {
        return <div>
          {loading ? <p>Loading...</p> : <button onClick={this.getSlots} className='button'>Show me dates</button>}
        </div>
      }
      return null;
    }


    render() {
        const { doctorSlots, timingSlot, hasTiming, loading } = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                {this.renderButton()}
                {doctorSlots === null ? <p></p> : <PatientSelectDay props={doctorSlots} timing={timingSlot} getTimings={this.getTiming} />}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PatientAppointmnent;


class PatientSelectDay extends Component {
state = {  
      options: [...this.props.props].map(obj => {
        return {value: `${obj}`, label: `${obj}`}
      }),
      timingOptions: [...this.props.timing],
      open_id: [],
      part_id: '',
      doctorDay: 'day',
      doctorTiming: 'timing',
  }

  changeSingleHandler = e => {
    this.setState({ part_id: e ? e.value : '' });
  };

  changeHandler = e => {
    let add = this.state.open_id;
    add.push(e.map(x => x.value));
    this.setState({ open_id: e ? add : [] });
  };

  saveState = (option) => {
...save selected options
  }  

  render() {
    const {options, timingOptions} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
            <div className='carousel'>
          {options.map((option, index) => {
                const timing = timingOptions[index].map(obj => {
                  return {value: `${obj}`, label: `${obj}`}});
                return(
                <div key={index}>
                  <Select
                    name="open_id"
                    value={option}
                    onChange={this.changeSingleHandler}
                    options={option}
                    className='select'
                  /> 
                  <Select
                    name="open_id"
                    value={this.state.open_id}
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    options={timing}
                    className='select'
                  /> 
            <button onClick={() => this.saveState(option)} className='button-left'>Select Days</button>
            </div>
            )
  })}
            </div>
          </div>
          )
    }
  }
export default PatientSelectDay;
```